# Is it safe to store only the Firebase Storage download URL token (not the full path)?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an Angular app using Firebase Storage to store user uploaded photo files. After the user uploads a file, I call getDownloadURL() (returns Observable) to get the full public URL path. I want to store the URL string in a Firestore database so it can be bound to an img html element src property for display on a web page. That will save me from having to call the Storage API to get every image URL one-by-one asynchronously.

This URL includes a token value in the query string which I assume is un-guessable and used for security as a sort of password. **To save space, should I only store the token in the database?** I can assemble the rest of the cloud folder path using variables - the token is the unique part. The full URL path is quite long as you can see. Do you think the rest of the URL path will ever change?

*Example Firebase Storage download URL (not real)*

https: -- //firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ -- v0/b/my-bucket-name-goes-here/o/T4uk5DnzXlO1C7hs9HrSdb7yxsM2%2Fthumb%2FcX2kCobDqdRgN3snefYh.jpg?alt=media&token=238b33ad-f823-4876-a5e2-626ca157ed10

Comment: This is, of course, a personal preference call, but I would never break it up like that. Is it possible? Probably... but I feel it introduces too much complexity & more opportunity for things to break, especially for the little bit of space you'd be saving. For me, the trade off (space saved) vs (potential to break) isn't worth it.

Comment: Understood. The other option I didn't mention is to store the folder path and then call getDownloadUrl() every time to get the public URL to be absolutely sure the Firebase Storage URL didn't change, but that is even more server call overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only guarantee that you receive from the API is that the entire URL will fetch the file in storage.  You should treat it opaquely and not try to break down or interpret its components.

Comment: Yes however the first path of the path is simply the Firebase Storage bucket name and folder tree. Since I know exactly where I uploaded the file to, that part should never change. I was thinking it might save database space to now store so many long URLs. I agree it is at least slightly safer to store the entire URL. I wonder if that is what everyone is doing in this situation.

Comment: Everyone is just storing the URL.  I don't think it's a good idea to prematurely optimize for space, at the risk of profoundly breaking your app if something about the implementation of the URLs changes over time.

Comment: Yes, but if something about the implementation of the URL changes over time, caching the download URL in the database will also be broken. Yes? So perhaps the only truly safe way is to call getDownloadURL() every time the URL is required by the app. 

However I rather not add that overhead so I'll stick with your advice to store the full URL and play it safe and easy. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm saying that the format of the download URLs for future generated URLs could change, then your code that tries to interpret them might break.  But once you have a URL, it should be safe to use forever.

Comment: @DougStevenson so the result of `getDownloadUrl` is safe to be stored in firestore ?